# WEB3.JS - Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert

Tags: javascript, solidity, web3js

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const fs = require('fs')
const web3 = new Web3("ws://localhost:7545");


const contract_address = "0x7484d32e891817702c5d7c764dBF7e592000b415"; 


async function web3Contract() {
    const contract_abi = fs.readFileSync('./build/contracts/Bottle.json', 'utf8')
    const abi = JSON.parse(contract_abi).abi;
    // console.log(abi);
    const Bottle = await new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contract_address);
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
    Bottle.methods.setName("Palm").send({from:accounts[0]});
    const greeting = await Bottle.methods.getGreeting().call();

    console.log(greeting);
}

async function run() {
    try {
        await web3Contract();
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('Your error is this - ' , err);
    } finally {
        console.log('finally');
    }
}

run();
```

```
pragma solidity >=0.5.16 <0.9.0;

contract Bottle {
    // setName and getGreeting. — set name is to set the name inside the smart contract 
   //  and store it on the blockchain, and getGreeting should say “Hello Name” where name is what’s stored on the blockchain.
    string newName;

   function setName(string memory _name) public returns(string memory) {
      newName = _name;
      return newName;
   }

    function getGreeting() view public returns(string memory){
        return newName;
    }

}
```

I'm getting this error "Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert".

I'm using the contract address that truffle gives me when I migrate it. I'm also using ganache and it is showing these transactions going through. Also I console.log(abi) and it is correctly showing the abi.
Not sure how to fix this.

console.log(abi) value is this - https://gyazo.com/73f4668d687a512e63c7fdf195460ea6

Also the ganache server is this https://gyazo.com/f47eeaec32e4fbd25a33d37ba5867620

Comment: Please share the Solidity code for `getGreeting()` and it's dependencies (i.e. if it calls an external contract, share the external contract relevant parts as well).

Comment: I updated the code.

Comment: The contract seems all right. Possibly it's an issue with the ABI JSON? What is its value? ... Or with the network? Can you doublecheck that you deployed the contract on the same network that the provider `ws://localhost:7545` is (i.e. both local network, and not deploying to some testnet using Truffle)?

Comment: I edited the code. I double check everything. Not sure if these are the outputs I want.